# UITableViewCell resize height WITHOUT changing it's content lauout

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

This is killing me!
I have a `UITableView` with cells that has an image, name and phone number in them.
Look here:

[image]

Now, I want to expend the cell's height when touching it so I can add some buttons in there. When I expend the cell, I also change it's bg image (to a higher one).
I do it using `[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];` and it works nice, animates the cell down smoothly, except that it also changes the cell's content:

[image: Cell's content resized :(]

**Anything I can do so the content will stay as it was after cell resizing?**

BTW, i did try using,
`[_tableView beginUpdates];`
`[_tableView endUpdates];`
but the cell just "jumped" to it's new height so I gave it up.

Comment: Either apply proper resizing rules so that labels/image superview is not resized when the cell view is resized or override cell `layoutSubviews` to control subviews position. The former solution in general works with frame, the latter with position, you can combine them as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for the answers, but nothing helped.
At first I used the built-in cell items (imageView, textLabel, detailTextLabel) and these are changing sizes as the cell transitions.
When I added my custom subviews, with defined frames, to the cell it worked.

Answer (score 2):

You need to be aware of the layouting of the contentView.

If you use **Autolayout**, check your constraints (`cell.contentView.constraints`). If you use **UIViewAutoresizing**, set correct autoresizingMasks (`cell.contentView.autoresizingMask`) for all subviews of contentView. You could also try to turn off autoResizing (`cell.contentView.autoresizesSubviews = NO`), but this will likely result in wrong results.

Also I'm wondering, why there is an arrow in the cell backgroundImage? Probably you should use other images too.

Comment: The arrow looks pretty nice, it reminds a standard popover which must be a good user experience.

Comment: The bg image is borrowed from another project. Once i solve this problem I'll create my own images :)

Answer (score 2):

You can create two custom cells one before expansion and another one for expanded cell.
when you touch the cell store the selected cell `indexpath` and while reloading the table, in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` check the `indexpath` and load cell accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `UIViewAutoresizing` mask of name and phone number labels (or any other UI elements in the content) to fixed top margin.

Answer (score 0):

Try following delegation method to set height of tableview

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 70.0;
}
```

You can create an array of images

```
imgPaths = [[NSArray alloc] 
                initWithObjects:
                [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"abc" ofType:@"png"],
                [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"def" ofType:@"png"],nil];
```

Add it in cellForRowAtIndexPath methods.

example:

```
[cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[imgPaths objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
```